# How to read a header from a CSV file using python

Tags: python

i tried the following script as per ur suggestion and i get an error import csv

```
def main():
    col_name = "\\xyz-abc\Procz(abcd)\Digital"
    with open('C:\\read.csv', 'rb') as inf:
        reader = csv.reader(inf)
        col_index = next(reader).index(col_name)
        highest = max(rec[col_index] for rec in reader)
        print "test"
main()
```

I get an error `ValueError: '\\\\xyz-abc\Procz(abcd)\Digital' is not in list`   please help me..
I think the script is not reading the column header.

Comment: Can you show us your csv file

Comment: It's very possible that this code is working fine, but the string you provided for `col_name` isn't actually in the header. We need to see the first few lines of your csv file to determine if this is the case. I would also suggest trying to print `next(reader)` to see what it's giving you.

Comment: actually i need the script to read from the column header \\xyz-abc\Procz(abcd)\Digital and this is just an example. should I use next(reader) instead of col_name ????

Answer (score 2):

Give this a go. Prevent the back-slashes being interpreted as escape characters by using a raw string

```
col_name = r"\\xyz-abc\Procz(abcd)\Digital"
```

Comment: Thats how it is given in the CSV. The script should identify that column and get the max value from that column.

Comment: @Siddharth I understand. Try your script with the lower-case `r` in front of the col_name string. This makes it a _raw_ string.

Comment: @Siddarth. ok. It would definitely help to see the first few lines of your csv file. Could you post them? Perhaps use https://gist.github.com

Comment: I think i figured out the issue... my header name starts with \\DHL-ABC001\ABC\MBB written. Since the header name starts with \\DHL the script is not able to read the header. Is there any solution for this ???

Comment: @Siddarth: I'm not sure what you mean. `\\DHL` should not stop your script from running. It's just a string. I can run your code on a csv file with header row `\\DHL-ABC001\ABC\MBB,\\xyz-abc\Procz(abcd)\Digital,col3` and it works fine. Please post the first few lines of your csv

Comment: These are the values  
138245533696.00
140600864768.00
140600864768.00
140600864768.00
140600864768.00
148528623616.00
149602365440.00
151749849088.00
151749849088.00
151749849088.00
153897332736.00
153897332736.00
153897332736.00
156044816384.00
156044816384.00
is there a possibility to skip \\DHL ??

Comment: I want a way to skip the backslash so that it can identify the header

Comment: \\DTTT-TKAKNE015\Process(My Engine)\Memory Bytes

Comment: And the values are definitely comma separated? I can see nothing with these column headers that would cause the csv reader to fail. You are sure that the col_header you are checking for is defined as a raw string (with r'')?

Comment: +1 for your answer, and +10 for perseverance in the face of adversity.

Comment: I have to try using the raw string..The following is the script:        def getHeader():
 col_name= "\\DTTT-TKAKNE015\Process(My Engine)\Memory Bytes"
 #col_name = col_name1.strip()
 with open('C:\My_STANDARD_KK007_20110506.csv', 'rb') as inf:
  reader = csv.reader(inf)
  col_index = next(reader).index(col_name)
  highest = max(rec[col_index] for rec in reader)
  print "Value:",highest
getHeader()

Comment: Hi Rob now the script is working fine.. when i used raw string. Thanks for ur support buddy.

Comment: I have another query:  Requirement:

BBSy::Bytes,0,0,0,0,0,3367744544,4626349536,
BBSy::Symbols,0,0,0,0,0,3567526,4900794,5471915,5691940,
BBSy::Cre,0,0,0,0,0,3567526,4900794,5471915,

I need help on the following requirement

The script should search for BBSy::Symbols and display the last value that is '5691940'.

Please help me on the following issue

It would be nice if we can store the value to a particular column in a CSV file.

Comment: @Siddharth Excellent. Glad it works. If using the raw string for your col_name works, please accept the answer; it will make it clearer for anyone with a similar problem in the future (and I get some points!)

Comment: @Siddarth Is that new data also in a csv file? A separate csv file from the original one? You should probably open a new question, to prevent this one from becoming too long and complicated

Comment: no it is in separate file.. i am not able to post a new question.

Comment: @Siddarth ok. Is that one long comma-separated line, or is it 3 lines, each starting with BBSys::

Comment: Also, you run the risk of having this question closed if you ask additional, unrelated questions in the comments. You really should create a new question